# MVC Workflow Model State

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, workflow, state

I have a MVC app that has one or more workflows within them, very similar but different workflows. For example:

- Step 1
- Step 2

  - Step 2a (conditional on Step 2 & state)
  - Step 2b (conditional on Step 2a & state)
- Step 3
- Finish

Each step has specific validation tied to it. Currently the actions are setup something to the following:

```
public controller Test
{
    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        // validation (10-30 lines)

        // Store against model

        return RedirectToAction("Step2");
    }

    public ActionResult Step2()
    {
        // validation (10-30 lines)

        // Store against model

        return someCondition ? RedirectToAction("Step2a") : RedirectToAction("Step3");
    }

    public ActionResult Step2a()
    {
        // validation (10-30 lines)

        // Store against model

        return RedirectToAction("Step2");
    }
}
```

1. Is there a way of doing `return GetNextStep()`? I was thinking a state machine, but I am unsure if this is the best pattern due to the conditional elements and state (*and where should the state live? Inside the model or seperate state object?*).
2. What is the best way of validating at each step?

Comment: are you using different Model for each step?

Comment: Currently yes. But I am looking to re-model to using a single model and binding to the correct property only.

Comment: So you can build a Model with all the fields as in 5 steps you need. And in each step you can pass the control to the controller and return a next step view.

Comment: Shall I help you out with Different Models (For each step) and all of them used in a view model. OR 1 single model and to iterate into 5 steps?

Comment: @Reddy Could you post an example of 1 model and 5 steps please?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model with all the fields required in 5 steps.

```
public class FullForm
{

// fields for step 1 

public string FirstFieldOfStep1 {get; set;}
....

// put as many fields are there in step 1

//Fields For second step

public string FirstFieldOfStep2 {get; set;}

// all your conditional fields goes here
....


//Fields For Third step

public string FirstFieldOfStep3 {get; set;}


}
```

Now in your View you can have 5 different HTML pages (each for each step).

And in your Main View (lets name as MainForm.cshtml) You can have a switch case something like.

```
    @{

    switch(find which field is yet to be filled)
    {
    case(if FirstFieldOfStep1 is null) : @Html.RenderPartial("Step1.cshtml");

    case(if FirstFieldOfStep2 is null) :  @Html.RenderPartial("Step2.cshtml");

    case(if FirstFieldOfStep3 is null) :  @Html.RenderPartial("Step3.cshtml");

    }
}
```

In your Step2.cshtml You can check for the condition and call the other two views accordingly.

In your Controller you can do this.

```
public controller Test
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Step1(FullForm fullFormDetails)
    {
       if(all the required fields are available with new values)
       {
          //save in database and proceed.
        }
      else
      {
         return View ("MainForm",fullFormDetails)
       }  

    }

}
```

So basically what you are doing here is you are collecting the form details bit by bit and each time in your controller you are passing the entire data to the view so that it can render the next page that need to collect data. So at last you will save the entire form only once.

You can  you custom validation attribute in MVC so that you need not validate the form each time in controller. you can just have a look at here for building custom attribute and change it accordingly for your application which is a clean method. [Custom attribute in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442515/Uploading-and-returning-files-in-ASP-NET-MVC) .

Comment: I am not using Visual Studio so look up for the typos.